# Python, faking stdin

Tags: python, version-control, stdin, pipe

I'm currently writing an abstraction over darcs in python, however once I'm trying to send data to my repository, the repository requests for a key; I was thinking wether it was possible to make python send keys to darcs, using stdin, or whatever, to emulate what the user would be typing, since in this way; I could allow users to simply store a file with their information in, and python would simply read this file and fire off its contents.

```
def execute(cmd):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    proc.wait()
```

Is the code I'm using to fire up darcs; execute("darcs %s" % (parems))

Comment: How are you launching darcs? Via subprocess?

Comment: subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True) - yes exactly

Comment: Well, how far have you got with that? Are you using `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` and `.communicate()`? Show us your code.

Comment: @Skeen: Please **update** your question with all the facts.  Please post enough code that we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Not far at all, actually nowhere, I kinda gave up trying stuff; I considered some pipe thingy, but I'm not sure how to. - Hence why I'm here, pretty much just looking for a way to get started; which one of the two you mention is the best one, in your opinion, what are their strengths and weeknesses.

Comment: Not far at all, actually nowhere, I kinda gave up trying stuff; I considered some pipe thingy, but I'm not sure how to. - Hence why I'm here, pretty much just looking for a way to get started; which one of the two you mention is the best one, in your opinion, what are their strengths and weeknesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

> The `subprocess` module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes.

The [`subprocess.Popen.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method is used for communications:

> `Popen.communicate(input=None)`
>
> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate. **The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child process**, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.
>
> communicate() returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata).
>
> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the Popen object with `stdin=PIPE`. Similarly, to get anything other than None in the result tuple, you need to give `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` too.

Comment: I'm using that module to create the process, however, I'm not sure how exactly to connect the pipes.

Comment: I think this will be the solution for me :)

Comment: @Skeen, interesting.This is pretty straightforward solution and most people thought you needed pexpect from your original question. Thanks. Glad that your problem is solved.

Comment: Actually I tried to use pexports, however theres no windows support

Answer (score 4):

Try `pexpect`, which is built exactly for this purpose (automating other interactive apps).

See:  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/

A usage example from the docs:

```
   import pexpect
   child = pexpect.spawn ('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
   child.expect ('Name .*: ')
   child.sendline ('anonymous')
   child.expect ('Password:')
   child.sendline ('noah@example.com')
   child.expect ('ftp> ')
   child.sendline ('cd pub')
   child.expect('ftp> ')
   child.sendline ('get ls-lR.gz')
   child.expect('ftp> ')
   child.sendline ('bye')
```

Comment: This really seems like its what I'm looking for :) - I guess the expect just listens on stdout? and sendline just feeds stdin?

Comment: Yes, it abstracts away all the details of stdin/stdout to your subprocess.

Comment: Windows?  Oh.  You should clarify that in your question, and add a "windows" tag.

Comment: you could say so, but I'm trying to be platform independent, hence why I'm using python. :)